# barcode scanner along with cordova camera preview

Tags: angular, cordova, camera, barcode-scanner

How to use phonegap barcode scanner plugin together with cordova-plugin-camera-preview so that when i click on scan button in my angular application the camera previews inside my application and scans the barcode and gives me the result

Comment: Please include some code examples of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your making it complicated for yourself

The barcode scanner plugin which is

> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

The mentioned barcode scanner above already have an access to the camera you dont have to use another plugin like the one you mentioned the camera preview plugin for cordova

Example:

```
//plugin options
var options= {
      preferFrontCamera : true, // iOS and Android
      showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
      showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
      torchOn: true, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
      saveHistory: true, // Android, save scan history (default false)
      prompt : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
      resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500
      formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
      orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
      disableAnimations : true, // iOS
      disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS and Android
  }

 //success callback
function onSuccess(result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
 }

//error callback
function onError(error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
}

cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Comment: But this will open the camera app separately not inside a container in my application..like the ones all mobile applications have to scan qrcode without opening another camera app

Comment: With that said i can assure that you cant do that using this plugin this plugin has only 3 parameters there is no way to pass a base64 image on it or whatsoever

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315320/can-cordova-camera-open-in-side-cordova-application according to this answer camera can be made to open inside a div.I just want to connect the two I.e when I click on scan this camera preview is triggered not my Mobile's local camera

Comment: yes you can open the camera inside the app but the fact that the barcode scanner plugin dose support an image as an input it can only take image from its own camera function

Comment: you would need a barcode plugin that takes an image as an argument